# play video in background swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

hello im trying to play video in background but its give an error and the error is " unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value " and im already set the video in Bundle and select copy if need

this the my code

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var paused: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Grad_Cap_Toss", withExtension: "mp4")


        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url!)
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        avPlayer.volume = 0
        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none

        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: Selector(("playerItemDidReachEnd:")),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,object: avPlayer.currentItem)

    }
```

please any body have ideas for that , thank you

Comment: Is `url` nil at `AVPlayer(url: url!)`?

Comment: no its not nill !

Comment: Then, which line are you crashing on?

Comment: sorry i don't understand the first question , Exactly same line that you asking about before

Comment: Let me try again....  If you use `print(url)` right after the `let url...` line, what does it show you?

Comment: i just try that its give me nil !!?

Answer (score 6):

> 1. First, drag and drop video file in your project.
>
>    2. Then import AVFundation.
>    3. Add example: var player: AVPlayer?
>    4. @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView! - Connect view from storyboard to your VC class.
>    5. After that, you paste this code into your ViewController.
>    6. call "playBackgoundVideo()" in your viewDidLoad()

```
private func playBackgoundVideo() {
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "your_video_here", ofType:"mp4") {
        let filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
        player = AVPlayer(url: filePathUrl)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.videoView.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem, queue: nil) { (_) in
            self.player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.player?.play()
        }
        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player?.play()
    }
}
```

This is swift 4.0
it works ^__^

Comment: Implemented above code, video works in the simulator but doesn't works in device, any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and followed the instructions from Rick's answer to resolve it. 
My problem was that I didn't have the video file in the bundle resources.
Check if your video file is listed in Copy Bundle Resources under Build Phases in the project. If not , use the + button to add the file in there. 
Also you might be missing the avPlayer.play() statement in your code.

Comment: This should be the approved answer. Worked for me! Thx

Answer (score 3):

I was also trying to play a video in the background of my login page's view controller. I think the main issue is that the syntax you're using is deprecated.

Your code might look like the following:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var blackOverlay: UIView!

// init video background and its path
var player: AVPlayer?
let videoURL: NSURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "videoName", withExtension: "mp4")! as NSURL

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Adds a black overlay to the looped video in question

    blackOverlay.alpha = 0.75;
    blackOverlay.layer.zPosition = 0;

    // begin implementing the avplayer 

    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    player?.isMuted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    playerLayer.frame = view.frame

    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player?.play()

    // add observer to watch for video end in order to loop video

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loopVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player)

    // if video ends, will restart  

    func playerItemDidReachEnd() {
        player!.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
    }

}
    // maybe add this loop at the end, after viewDidLoad
   // func loopVideo() { player?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero) player?.play()}}
```

Please let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag and drop video file in your project.
2. Then import AVFundation
3. List item
4. @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!, @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!,@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!,@IBOutlet weak var loginBtn: UIButton!
5. Connect view from storyboard to your VC class.
6. And then paste the given code in your ViewController and call *playVideo()* function in *viewDidLoad()*.

   func playVideo(){
       guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "intro", ofType: "mp4") else {
           return
       }

       let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
       let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
       playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
       playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
       self.videoLayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
       player.play()


       videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(image)
       videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(label)
       videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(loginBtn)
       videoLayer.bringSubviewToFront(signupBtn)
   }

Answer (score 0):

If `url` is `nil` and the video is being successfully copied into the bundle, the likely problem is case sensitivity. Make sure the filename is using the correct case. The iOS device filesystem is case sensitive, where as the iPhone simulator is not.

Comment: i set every things will same like name and in the bundles but still not working :(

Comment: `Bundle.main.url(forResource:withExtension:)` will only return `nil` if it cannot find a file with the matching name and extension. This can happen if any of the following are true: a) the file is not included in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase, b) the supplied name does not match (case sensitive) or c) the supplied extension does not match (case sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem when I tried to play video background. I think it is the problem of video resource.

I resolved the problem like this way.

When you drag your video, you should check both of 'Copy items if needed' and 'Add to targets'.
Or you can just right click on the project navigator, click 'Add' to add resource.